# Tengo resultados en la búsqueda: '1 Búsqueda encontrada' pero no aparecen en la tabla - Angular12

Tags: angular, busqueda, angular12

Logré que la búsqueda funcione (que antes no lo hacía).
Cuando busco "Lourdes del Mar", tal cual está escrito ahí, lo encuentra, me dice '1 Búsqueda encontrada'.
Lo que yo necesito es que sea indiferente si se escribe en mayúscula o minúscula, y además que no solo busque por nombre, sino también por DNI, fecha de nacimiento, etc.

Aquí mi código:

`busqueda.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="titulo text-center">Buscar un acta</h1>
<div class="busqueda">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input (keyup)="onSubmit($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" type="text" id="searchKey" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." />
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="txt text-center">La búsqueda se puede realizar por nombre, apellido, DNI, fecha de nacimiento o lugar de nacimiento.</p>
    <div *ngIf="condition; then block1; else block2"></div>
    <ng-template #block1>
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Buscando resultados para
        <strong>{{prevText}}</strong>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #block2>
        <h6>{{res_cnt}} Búsqueda encontrada</h6>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="tabla">
                    <th>Apellido y Nombre</th>
                    <th>DNI</th>
                    <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                    <th>Lugar de Nacimiento</th>
                    <th>Acta de Nacimiento</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="tabla" *ngFor="let user of actas">
                    <td class="txt-left">{{user.nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.DNI}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.FechaNacimiento}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.LugarNacimiento}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.ActaNacimiento}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

`busqueda.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-busqueda',
  templateUrl: './busqueda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./busqueda.component.css'],
})


export class BusquedaComponent implements OnInit {

  searchValue: string = null;
  items = [];
  condition: boolean = null;
  prevText: string = '';
  actas = [{
    "nombre": "Lourdes del Mar",
    "DNI": "40.775.265",
    "FechaNacimiento": "17/02/1998",
    "LugarNacimiento": "La Rioja, Capital",
    "ActaNacimiento": "VER"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Lede, Milva Ernestina",
    "DNI": "44.123.456",
    "FechaNacimiento": "24/04/2004",
    "LugarNacimiento": "La Rioja, Capital",
    "ActaNacimiento": "VER"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Lede, Guadalupe Esmeralda",
    "DNI": "01.234.567",
    "FechaNacimiento": "13/11/2005",
    "LugarNacimiento": "La Rioja, Capital",
    "ActaNacimiento": "VER"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Lede, Ángel Gustavo",
    "DNI": "23.670.990",
    "FechaNacimiento": "07/01/1974",
    "LugarNacimiento": "Buenos Aires, Capital Federal",
    "ActaNacimiento": "VER"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Mansilla Kukulis, Susana Estela",
    "DNI": "23.963.589",
    "FechaNacimiento": "24/06/1974",
    "LugarNacimiento": "La Rioja, Capital",
    "ActaNacimiento": "VER"
  }
  
];
  res_list = [];
  res_cnt: number = 0;
    
  onSubmit($event){
    if($event.keyCode === 13){
      this.condition = true;
      this.prevText = this.searchValue;
      this.res_cnt = 0;
      this.res_list = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.condition = false;
        for(let i=0; i<this.actas.length; i++){
          if(this.actas[i].nombre === this.searchValue
             || this.actas[i].nombre.startsWith(this.prevText)){
            this.res_cnt += 1;
            this.res_list.push(this.actas);
          }
        }
      }, 3000);
      this.searchValue = null;
    }
  }

    //paginación
    pageOfItems: Array<any>;

    onChangePage(pageOfItems: Array<any>) {
      // update current page of items
      this.pageOfItems = pageOfItems;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(123);

    this.items = Array(150).fill(0).map((x, i) => ({ id: (i + 1)}));
  }
}
```

Busqué por internet y no encuentro la lógica que necesito para mi aplicación.

Si es que sirve, me guié con este [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-input-value-search-box-and-enter-it-in-angularjs-component-using-enter-key/).

Comment: es angular12, no me deja incluir esa etiqueta

Comment: listo! podrás ayudarme?

Comment: La lógica... `Lede, Guadalupe Esmeralda` ¿es igual al valor de búsqueda `.toLowerCase()` ?

Comment: no te entiendo, perdon

Comment: Tu If statement `if(this.actas[i].nombre === this.prevText.toLowerCase()  || this.actas[i].nombre.startsWith(this.prevText))` ¿entiendes lo que quiere decir esto? Por otro lado, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: la verdad que lo entiendo minimamente, estoy aprendiendo y me cuesta! mis profesores me dijeron que haga las preguntas aquí, no era la idea pero bueno, no me quedó otra. Por eso estoy empezando a conocer la plataforma, así que gracias x el link q me enviaste, lo estoy leyendo.

Comment: [mira este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/288924/28035), es una solucion generica

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

```
if(this.actas[i].nombre === this.prevText.toLowerCase()
         || this.actas[i].nombre.startsWith(this.prevText)){
        this.res_cnt += 1;
        this.res_list.push(this.actas[i]);
      }
```

Pues, cada vez que se hace búsquedas de cadenas de texto o bien mandas todo a mayúsculas (uppercase) o bien mandas todo a verificar en minúsculas (lowercase).

Mira este ejemplo:

```
const str1 = 'Saturday night plans';    
console.log(str1.startsWith('sat'));
// expected output: false
```

En tu código, tienes:

```
this.prevText = this.searchValue;
```

Eso se define luego de dar un ENTER `($event.keyCode = 13)`.

Por lo tanto, si has colocado `Lede, Guadalupe Esmeralda`, esto se va a traducir como `lede, guadalupe esmeralda`, por lo tanto...

- Primera parte del IF, termina siendo FALSE por obvias razones.
- Segunda parte del IF, termina siendo FALSE porque el startsWith nunca se cumple entre mayúscula/minúscula.

Como ambas condiciones son falsas, lo demás no sigue.

En esta carrera tienes que acostumbrarte a leer la documentación oficial del lenguaje que estás usando, es una ventaja enorme. Me sorprende la actitud de tus docentes, no sé si mandarlos a capacitarse en temas de docencia o darle las gracias por haberte motivado a llegar aquí, o ambas cosas en todo caso.

Lectura recomendada:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Estuve buscando para poder entender y sinceramente no logro hacerlo (encontrarle la lógica), yo me guié de este [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-input-value-search-box-and-enter-it-in-angularjs-component-using-enter-key/) para hacer mi buscador, alguna idea de cómo readaptarlo? porfa lo necesito entender y hacer urgente :(

Comment: Normalmente NO respondo cuando NO hay muestras de intentos; copiar y pegar código, lo hace cualquiera, ¿dónde está el esfuerzo de por medio?. `this.actas[i].nombre` manda eso a minúsculas en el código e intenta nuevamente :D

Comment: ahhh, si modifique el codigo, logre que me genere la busqueda, pero aun no encuentro la logica, ahí te dejo lo que modifique

Comment: editado para que puedas verlo

Comment: `logre que me genere la busqueda, pero aun no encuentro la logica,` La vas a encontrar si realizas N intentos + te pones a analizar el flujo de datos. Buena suerte :D

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Visual Code y un linter en tu proyecto, te lo indica el mismo editor: `this.actas[i]` es un objeto. Ej:

```
actas: {
    nombre: 'Lalo';
    DNI: '111111111';
    FechaNacimiento: '03/03/2003';
    LugarNacimiento: 'Buenos Aires';
    ActaNacimiento: '2331231221312323';
}
```

Y vos estas preguntando si todo eso es igual a `prevText`, que es un simple string. Deberias comparar contra una de las propiedades del objeto.

Ademas, si hacer `toLowerCase()` de un string, seria conveniente que lo hagas tambien de las propiedades. A menos que estes segura que las mismas ya vienen en minusculas.

Por otra parte, `startsWith` no es un metodo disponible para el objeto this.actas[i]. Si es un metodo de string. Cuando compares contra las propiedades te desaparece ese error.

Si vas a usar varias veces el valor pprevio en minusculas, quizas te conviene `this.prevText = this.searchValue.toLowerCase();` y dejar de hacerlo abajo para cada propiedad.

Si ya estas guardandote las actas coincidentes en res_list, entonces 1this.res_cnt += 1;`no tiene sentido (podes usar`this.res_list.length`);

Si por alguna razon estas evitando [hacer debug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-sMmxfNxBM), podes loggear para intentar entender lo que va pasando. Ej. adentro del for:

```
console.log(`"${this.prevText}" vs "${this.actas[i].nombre.toLowerCase()}" === ${this.actas[i].nombre.toLowerCase() === this.prevText}?`);
console.log(`"${this.prevText}" vs "${this.actas[i].nombre.toLowerCase()}" startsWith? ${this.actas[i].nombre.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.prevText)}`);
console.log(`"${this.prevText}" vs "${this.actas[i].nombre.toLowerCase()}" includes? ${this.actas[i].nombre.toLowerCase().includes(this.prevText)}`);
```